# libpng12.so.0: cannot open shared object file: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64

Tags: linux, docker, shared-libraries, quartus

I'm trying to install Quartus 13.0 on a docker container but I have a trouble with libpng12 lib.

```
builder@580847ded665:~$ ls -ld $(locate -r libpng.*\.so.*)
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     18 Jan  6  2016 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 -> libpng12.so.0.54.0
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 149904 Jan  6  2016 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0.54.0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     35 Jan  6  2016 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0
builder@580847ded665:~$ xvfb-run -a /home/builder/altera/13.0/quartus/bin/tb2_install --enable
tb2_install: error while loading shared libraries: libpng12.so.0: cannot open shared object file: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
```

The problem is I have a 32 bit application trying to use a 64 bit library and it is not understanding it. Could anyone please help me to figure out how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you can do.
Download `libpng12-0` package from 
[here.](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libpng12-0)

Now head over to the folder where you've downloaded it and open the terminal from there. Switch to super user using:

```
sudo su
```

Install the downloaded package with the following command:

```
dpkg -i libpng12-0_1.2.50-1ubuntu2.14.04.3_amd64.deb; apt-get install -f
```

(The package name can change, make sure to change it accordingly).

If you get an error like this:

```
dpkg: error processing archive libpng12-0_1.2.50-1ubuntu2.14.04.3_amd64.deb (--install): trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libpng12-0/changelog.Debian.gz'
```

This means that you might have an existing libpng package installed on your system which is causing a conflict.
Do this:

```
mv /usr/share/doc/libpng12-0 /usr/share/doc/libpng12-0.backup
```

This means that you are moving the conflict causing directory to another location.

Finally,

```
dpkg -i libpng12-0_1.2.50-1ubuntu2.14.04.3_amd64.deb; apt-get install -f
```

My answer is specific to Bionic beaver and *64 architecture. You can checkout the link provided above to download other architecture-specific packages.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Try installing 32-bit version of libpng. On Debian it should be something like `apt-get install libpng16-16:i386`. If `tb2_install` keeps picking 64-bit version you might need to update `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to put 32-bit paths in front of 64-bit ones.

Another solution is to use 64-bit Quartus installer.

Comment: i have already tried this way, but it continued to fail... so, i just built a new docker image from 32-bit/debian with base packages and built a new one with installed quartus 13.0.0.156 over it. it is available under qatsi/ repo. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just battled with this to install Lattice iCEcube2 in Debian.
My solution:

Find the latest 32-bit libpng:

`aptitude search libpng`

Select the i:386 version, in my case:

`sudo aptitude install libpng16-16:i386`

Link libpng12.so.0 to the 32-bit libpng16.so.0:

In /usr/local/lib:

`sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16.37.0 libpng12.so.0`